# IndexError with dict in python,

Tags: python, dictionary

```
classes = []
due = []
minutes =[]
grade = []
classname = []
classnume = []
form_orderer = []
listobj = []

i = 0
n = 0
k = 0

def classesl(): #setup class list
    classesnum = int(input("How many classes do you have?"))
    classnume.append(classesnum)
    for _ in range(0,int(classnume[0])):
        classname = input("What is the class name??")
        classes.append(classname)

def duel(): #setup class list
    print("How many days is this assignment for", classes[i], "due in?")
    c = input() 
    due.append(c)

def minutesl(): #setup class list
    print("How many minutes will this take", classes[i], "?")
    e = input()
    minutes.append(e)

def gradesl(): #setup class list
    print("What is your grade in that", classes[i], "?")
    g = input()
    grade.append(g) 

def getvars():
    global i 
    for _ in range(0,int(classnume[0])):
        duel()
        minutesl()
        gradesl()
        make_dicts()
        i += 1


def form_order():
        for n in range(0,int(classnume[0])):
            a = int(minutes[n])
            b = int(grade[n])
            form_orderer.append(a/b)
            print(form_orderer)
            n += 1

def make_dicts():
        for k in range(0,int(classnume[0])):
                dictx = {'keyz': 'valz'}
                dictx.update({'class': classes[k], 'form_order': int(form_orderer[k])})
                listobj.append(dictx)
                k += 1

def sort(form_orderer):
    size = len(form_orderer)
    for x in range(form_orderer):
        for y in range(form_orderer-x-1):
            if(form_orderer[y] > form_orderer[y+1]):
                tmp = form_orderer[j]
                form_orderer[y] = form_orderer[y+1]
                form_orderer[y+1] = tmp

def setup():
    while True:
        classesl()
        getvars()
        form_order()
        make_dicts()
       # sort(form_orderer)
        print()
        break

setup()
```

I was wondering how would I get it so the form_orderer list corresponds with a classes list in a dict. So I can then print out the classes in order based off of the order of the form_order list sorted from least to greatest. I already have the bubble sort method down, just need help with the dict.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: **Use function parameters, not a bunch of global variables!!!!** This bug should be the least of your concerns right now!

Comment: And, a bit less important, variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` format, not `camelCase` or anything else.

Comment: Why are you immediately breaking out of a `while True` loop? What language did you learn to program in?

Answer (score 0):

You call make_dicts twice, which leads to an exception, it's called in get_vars and in setup, if i comment it out in get_vars i don't get any errors

```
classes = []
due = []
minutes =[]
grade = []
classname = []
classnume = []
form_orderer = []
listobj = []

i = 0
n = 0
k = 0

def classesl(): #setup class list
    classesnum = int(input("How many classes do you have?"))
    classnume.append(classesnum)
    for _ in range(0,int(classnume[0])):
        classname = input("What is the class name??")
        classes.append(classname)

def duel(): #setup class list
    print("How many days is this assignment for", classes[i], "due in?")
    c = input() 
    due.append(c)

def minutesl(): #setup class list
    print("How many minutes will this take", classes[i], "?")
    e = input()
    minutes.append(e)

def gradesl(): #setup class list
    print("What is your grade in that", classes[i], "?")
    g = input()
    grade.append(g) 

def getvars():
    global i 
    for _ in range(0,int(classnume[0])):
        duel()
        minutesl()
        gradesl()
        #make_dicts()
        i += 1


def form_order():
        for n in range(0,int(classnume[0])):
            a = int(minutes[n])
            b = int(grade[n])
            form_orderer.append(a/b)
            print(form_orderer)
            n += 1

def make_dicts():
        for k in range(0,int(classnume[0])):
                dictx = {'keyz': 'valz'}
                dictx.update({'class': classes[k], 'form_order': int(form_orderer[k])})
                listobj.append(dictx)
                k += 1

def sort(form_orderer):
    size = len(form_orderer)
    for x in range(form_orderer):
        for y in range(form_orderer-x-1):
            if(form_orderer[y] > form_orderer[y+1]):
                tmp = form_orderer[j]
                form_orderer[y] = form_orderer[y+1]
                form_orderer[y+1] = tmp

def setup():
    while True:
        classesl()
        getvars()
        form_order()
        make_dicts()
       # sort(form_orderer)
        print()
        break

setup()
```